# Regex to match URL prefix

Tags: c#, regex, url

I am trying to retrieve the prefix to a URL. The URL may look like one of the following:

1. "/Index"
2. "/Index/"
3. "/Index?var1=value1"

I want to be able to to extract the word "Index" out of it. I took a stab at it, but couldn't quite get it:

```
public string GetPrefix(string URL)
        {
            Regex regex = new Regex("^/(.*?)[\\?/]*");
            var matches = regex.Match(URL);
            return matches.Groups[1].ToString();
        }
```

Comment: Try this 
string pattern = "Index";
Regex rx = new Regex(pattern, RegexOptions.None);
MatchCollection mc = rx.Matches(Your_Url);

Comment: Question already answered below. Your method only matches for the literal word Index. This wouldn't work in cases where the Prefix is not Index.

Comment: Use the `System.Uri` class to retrieve information about an URL.

Comment: I can suggest something like [`var my_str = new Uri(new Uri("http://example.com"), URL).Segments.LastOrDefault());`](http://ideone.com/VonPfy).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```
^/([^/?])+
```

It's matching a `/` and any character that's not a `/` or a `?` *1* to *n* times. The match will also store the retrieved prefix in capture group `$1`.

Comment: This fails point number 3. I literally just want "Index" from all 3 cases. Your answer would output "Index?var1=value1", where as I want it to output "Index" only.

Answer (score 1):

```
^/(?<action>[^/?#]+)
```

You have to take care of all 3 "/", "?" and "#"

1. "/" gives a sub-action
2. "?" gives parameters
3. "#" gives page tag

Also, you can name a capture group for better annotation.

```
public string GetPrefix(string url)
{
    Regex regex = new Regex(@"^/(?<action>[^/?#]+)");
    var match = regex.Match(url);
    return match.Groups["action"].Value;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You may leverage `System.Uri` from `System.Web` namespace here. Even if you may have relative URLs, this should work:

```
using System.Web;
...
var URL = "/Index?var1=value1";
var uri = new Uri(new Uri("http://example.com"), URL); // Init the URI instance
Console.WriteLine(uri.Segments.LastOrDefault().Trim('/'));       // Get the last segment trimming any slashes
```

See the [IDEONE demo](http://ideone.com/VonPfy)